# Issue with Magento Category Display Settings

Tags: php, xml, magento, categories

In the category pages of my store only the default display settings work. For example: When I select the option to sort by name, nothing happens on the page if the default is to sort by price. But the url changes from: **www.example.com/some_category** to: **SAME URL#!___SID=U&dir=asc&order=name**.

And the same happens with the option to view (grid, list) and the display limit option (3, 6 ... All).

Note: The store was upgraded from version 1.7 to 1.8, but I can't tell you if that was the cause of the issue, because i don't know if this was working before.

Someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: The way you ask, the answer to your questions is simple: "you".

Comment: I think i get it. hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue changing `#%21` to `?` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If the culprit is the Vinagento extension go to `app/code/local/Vinagento/Vpager/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php`.

Change anything that says `#%21` to `?`.